# Use SPARQL to query properties with specific Subject

Tags: sparql, rdf, opendata

I am using DBpedia and I would like to Query all Properties that have as subject Actor. My attempt was the following:

```
PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
SELECT ?property
       ?b
WHERE {
    ?property a rdf:Property .
    :Actor ?property ?b
}
```

but the result is empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you're misunderstanding the concpet of the RDF data model I guess. a triple pattern like `?property a rdf:Property .` is supposed to return properties which itself are used in predicate position. If you want to add additional data about the property, then it will be the subject of a triple, i.e. `?property ?somePropertyAboutTheProperty ?o .` When you're talinking about e.g. properties whose domain is an actor, the it should be `?property rdfs:domain :Actor .`

Comment: `PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
SELECT ?property WHERE {
    ?property a rdf:Property .
    ?property rdfs:domain :Actor 
}`

Comment: This only works if such schema is given, and as RDF is schema less, instance data can use any other properties as well: `PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
SELECT distinct ?property WHERE {
 ?s a :Actor .
  ?s ?property ?o 
}`

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. Indeed you are right, but in this case
`PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
SELECT ?a
WHERE{
    ?a rdfs:domain :Actor .

}
LIMIT 10`
retrieves the same results as

`PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
SELECT ?a
WHERE{
    ?a rdfs:domain :Actor .
    ?a rdf:type rdf:Property
}
LIMIT 10`

Comment: Wish I could format my comments here in a more readable way

Comment: what do you mean by in this case? I know it's returning the same and `?a rdf:type rdf:Property` is somewhat redundant given that subjects of `rdfs:domain` are properties. So what's wrong with my query? It does return what you need, or not?

Comment: It does retreive what I wanted ^^